# What is an Internal Pointer Variable?

Tags: pointers

I know what pointers are but I don't know what internal pointer variables are.  Does anyone know what they are?  I came across this concept from a meme that is quite popular right now.  I can't find a decent explanation online anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can figure out by watching the original video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ranc3VvjI88

p.s. check 9:25 min =)

Answer (score 2):

Meme aside. The command

```c
int *parr = arr;
```

Can be read as:

> Integer pointer named `parr` is set to the memory address of the first element in the `int` array `arr`

Or, alternatively:

> Integer pointer named `parr` is set to the internal pointer of the variable `arr`

In this command, `arr` is some `int` array, e.g.,

```c
int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
```

When you use this syntax, you are telling `parr` to store the memory address of the first array element of `arr` (`arr[0]`). We call this memory address the **internal pointer variable**. All [composite data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_data_type) (e.g., arrays, structures, etc...) have its own internal pointer, and it is always the memory address of its first element. Note that it also works for strings as they are represented as `char` arrays in `C` and therefore are also a composite data type. This syntax is equivalent to `int *parr = &arr[0]`, but it is much more concise and therefore more adopted. When the compiler uses the internal pointer of the variable, we often say that "the variable **decays** into a pointer to its first element". On the other hand, we cannot write `int *p = i` if `i` is a single `int` because it is a [primitive data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_data_type) and therefore it has no internal pointer variable.

As a simple example, take a look in this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
    int *pi = i; // pi points to the internal pointer of the variable `i`, that is, the address of its first array element, 10.
    int d = 5;
    // int *pd = d; // you cannot do it as `d` has no internal since it is a primitive data type

    printf("The internal pointer of the int array is                      : %p\n"
           "The address of the first int array element is                 : %p\n"
           "The stored value (.i.e., the memory address) of the pointer is: %p\n",
           (void*)i, (void*)&i[0], (void*)pi);
    return 0;
}
```

It will output:

```
The internal pointer of the int array is                      : 0x7ffd2cfad750
The address of the first int array element is                 : 0x7ffd2cfad750
The stored value (.i.e., the memory address) of the pointer is: 0x7ffd2cfad750
```